# input type = checkbox problem

Tags: html

Why is this line not working?

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="no"/>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="false"/>
```

Even though i have specified no and false in checkbox value both are checked by default.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: All the answers are are partly right, because even if you didn't specify a checkbox to be `checked` by default, if it is checked manually, then the page is refreshed, it will retain it's checked value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

changing it to this will make the first unchecked, and the second checked :

```
 <input type="checkbox" />
 <input type="checkbox" checked />
```

To make the checkbox unchecked you need to remove the word "checked".

Answer (score 4):

Try this -

```
<input type="checkbox" checked/>
```

The attribute "Checked" will keep your checkbox checked by default. If you do not have this attribute mentioned, then the checkbox will be unchecked by default.

Comment: This is valid HTML but not valid XHTML. `checked=<some truthful expression>` is equivalent valid HTML.

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
```

this will pass html validation

Comment: Actually, it will pass xhtml validation.

Comment: It will pass both the HTML and XHTML validations.

Answer (score 2):

> Even though i have specified no and false in checkbox value both are checked by default.

this is default behaviour for boolean values in HTML elements.

Only removing the `checked` attribute altogether will make the element not checked.

The background is in [On SGML and HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2):

> Some attributes play the role of boolean variables (e.g., the selected attribute for the OPTION element). Their appearance in the start tag of an element implies that the value of the attribute is "true". Their absence implies a value of "false".
>
> Boolean attributes may legally take a single value: the name of the attribute itself (e.g., selected="selected").

Answer (score 0):

If you are purpose is validation and using jquery then you might need to use "change" event rather than "click".