# asp.net checkbox in gridview - checked property is missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In this asp.net gridview control, the checked property is always missing. I need to access the checked property via jquery

```
Gridview source:
            <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelected" runat="server" class="chkSummarySelection"  />
                   </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
```

Renders as :

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gv$ctl02$SelectedCheckBox" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gv_ctl02_SelectedCheckBox">
```

There is no checked property to access. 
I have tried

```
$(".chkSummarySelection").click(function () {
var chk;
chk = $(this).prop("checked");
chk = $(this).attr("checked");
chk = $(this).is(":checked");
chk = $(this).attr("value");
chk = $(this).val();
chk = jQuery(this).is(':checked');
});
```

but nothing is working

Comment: As a sidenote, keep in mind that a `CheckBox`, when rendered, doesn't have a property _checked_ when it is not checked.  See [this possibly related SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003303/input-type-checkbox-problem).
You can use the jQuery [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector for that like you did in your example.

Comment: I think this is what I'm after. The 'checked' property is not there at all, thus when I try to access it (even after it is checked) then because the property never existed, I cannot access it. Is there a way to force it to create the attribute 'checked'?

Comment: The property _checked_ should appear when the CheckBox is checked though, possibly without any value (it would just say 'checked' without any value assigned). Have you tried @Amiram's suggestion yet ?

Comment: had to encapsulate the checkbox                 $(".chkSummarySelection input[type='checkbox']").click(function () {}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jquery can't find your `CheckBox` since it doesn't have any css class. You need to change the `class` definition to `CssClass` (`class` is a keyword in c#):

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelected" runat="server" CssClass="chkSummarySelection"  />
```